# Reactjs: How to update parent's state from chidren?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React js.

I have a react component structured like this:

```
<Page>
  <List>
    <Item/>...
  </List>
  <View/>
</Page>
```

I want to update the content of `<View/>` according to the item I click in `<Item/>`, so I think I need to modify the state of `<Page/>`

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Suggestion for one way is to expose some onClick function from the child which gets called when a user clicks. Besides the exposed function, example Item could have attribute data-action, data-value the event propagates to some container element which handles the event.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/f5bt8jec/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

Parent:

```
...
    updateSomething: function(){
        console.log('From child');
    },
    render(){
       return(
          <Child 
              showUp={this.updateSomething} 
           />
        )
    }
...
```

And child something like this:

```
render()
    {
       return(
          <button onClick={this.props.showUp}>Show</button>
        )
    }
```